# Recovering typed texts in EditText generated at runtime

Tags: android, json, android-edittext

In my project I have some EDITTEXT being generated at runtime , the number of EDITTEXT is variable.
Must recover typed text and store in different variables , and then create a JSON object with it.

Here is the method I use to create the EditText :

```
public View editText(String nmLabel, String tpRender) {
    EditText e = new EditText(getBaseContext());
    e.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    // e.setHint("DATE");

    if(tpRender.equals("NUMBER")) {
        e.setHint("NUMBER");
    }
    else if(tpRender.equals("DATE")) {
        e.setHint("DATE");
    }
    else if(tpRender.equals("TEXT")) {
        e.setHint("TEXT");
    }
    e.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    e.setTextSize(20);

    return(e);
}
```

How do I get the text entered separately?

Comment: Did you try to make a simple Google search? This has been answer many times before. getText() gets you the current visible text that the user has input (or you grammatically set)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your EditTexts are created at runtime and you need to get the value from all of them to create your json, you could use a List and store your individual EditTexts there. Something like:

In the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/layout">

</LinearLayout>
```

In your activity,

```
    List<EditText> allEditTexts; // The List to hold all EditTexts
    LinearLayout layout; // The anchor layout

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
        allEditTexts = new ArrayList<EditText>();

        // I am running it three times, you can run as many times as you want

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        EditText editText = (EditText) editText("ANY LABEL", "NUMBER");
        layout.addView(editText);
        allEditTexts.add(editText);
        }

        // Now I am adding a button that will read the values from the List when clicked

        Button button = new Button(getApplicationContext());
        button.setText("Click");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                // Read the input here for all EditTexts. Then you can store it in some Array or process it differently. In my code I have just logged them.

                for (EditText editText : allEditTexts) {
                    Log.d("TEXTINPUT", editText.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        });
        layout.addView(button);
    }

    // This is the code that you have, almost untouched.
    public View editText(String nmLabel, String tpRender) {
        EditText e = new EditText(getBaseContext());
        e.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        // e.setHint("DATE");

        if (tpRender.equals("NUMBER")) {
            e.setHint("NUMBER");
        } else if (tpRender.equals("DATE")) {
            e.setHint("DATE");
        } else if (tpRender.equals("TEXT")) {
            e.setHint("TEXT");
        }
        e.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        e.setTextSize(20);
        allEditTexts.add(e);
        return (e);
    }
```

Hope this helps you!